# Angular - Controller refresh after using ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller which is basically one object, and inside of that object I have functions.

At the start I set the default values for variables and use `init()` function to get data from database.

The whole page works correctly except for one thing. Somehow I get in trouble when I use my ng-click to remove from chosen

```
  <a href="#" ng-click="listCtrl.removeFromChosen(chosen)" class="tagselect__close">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </a>
```

My whole controller is initialized again, so it sets all the values to default and calls `init()` function again. I can't figure out why is this happening.

```
"use strict";
myApp.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', '$cookies', '$http', function ($scope, $cookies, $http) {

    var listCtrl = {
        candidate: {},
        candidates: [],
        positions: [],
        chosenPositions: [],

        init: function () {
            listCtrl.getCandidates();
            listCtrl.getPositions();
        },
        getCandidates: function () {
            $http.get('api/v1/candidates/getCandidates.php').then(function (res) {
                listCtrl.candidates = res.data;
            });
        },
        getPositions: function () {
            $http.get('api/v1/positions/getPositions.php').then(function (res) {
                listCtrl.positions = res.data;
            });
        },
        removeFromChosen: function (position) {
            var index = listCtrl.getChosenIndex(position);
            listCtrl.chosenPositions.splice(index, 1);
            //console.log(listCtrl.chosenPositions);
        },
    };

    listCtrl.init();
    $scope.listCtrl = listCtrl;
}]);
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using an anchor tag to perform a click function, even if it's not linked to anything, it will refresh the page by default. In order to prevent this, pass the event object to the function you are calling and use prevent default like so:

```
removeFromChosen: function (event, position) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var index = listCtrl.getChosenIndex(position);
        listCtrl.chosenPositions.splice(index, 1);
        //console.log(listCtrl.chosenPositions);
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Cameron637, thanks for nice explenation. you are right :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove `href="#"` which is not compatible with ng-click.